# React routing with express on the backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I'm currently learning react just because all of the cool kids code in it and I was wondering how can I make an authentication app work. The idea is that I would have an express app with passport.js and mongoose to handle the authentication but I know that react is having it's own router and the server just gives it a static html file with all of the js bundled. The question is how can I make an application that has a login form on the / and then when the user is authenticated redirects to /dashboard where the username of the user that is logged in is shown? Do I make the route on the backend or do it in react? I really couldn't find any resources that would help me so stackoverflow is really my last option.

Any resources that would help me are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The frontend and the backend are two pieces of software, isolated and independent. You develop the frontend to make HTTP requests to the backend and perform some actions and view updates based on the backend responses.

The frontend handles the screens routing depending on the backend responses and the business logic you add.

Comment: So do I need to make requests from for ex port 80 (frontend) to port 3000?

Comment: Also should I build the react app and then serve it on the backend or should I just run npm run start in the frontend and node index.js in the backend

Comment: Yes, you need to send requests from the frontend (port 80 for example) to the backend in port 3000.

Comment: For development purpose, you only need to run npm start and node index.js in the backend. In a real no-development scenario, (qa server or production) you need to host your frontend compiled files in a web server to be able to expose them to the users from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is API. You can use node as backend server which will connect to your database. In frontend you will make post method for authentication with some data(for instance email, password) and in backend you will authenticate user and than send response. Here's link of how to start this project. Moreover you will need to know how to get data in react from api(I use axios for that) and how to manage routes in react(I use react router dom for that).

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react.amp